# HTTP 400 Error while consuming API (GET). What is the real problem?

Tags: angular, symfony, jwt

I have a symfony server which have jwt authentication and an angular client app who is making a request. I made a Login successfully and now I want to take some data to put in a select.

This data is the locals to assign to an employee.

This is my `api.service.ts` method:

```
getLocales(): Observable<any>
{
  const headers = { 'Content-Type':'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost:8000' }

  return (this.http.get( environment.url + 'api/local', { headers: headers }));
}
```

and I take all the locals at the next component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Cogemos los locales para listarlos en el select
    this.api.getLocales()
      .subscribe((locales) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(locales));
        this.locales = locales.locals;
      });
  }
```

I show it in HTML like this:

```
  <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6 mt-3">
                <label class="m-2" for="local">Local:</label>
                <select name="local" id="local">
                    <option *ngFor="let local of locales;" value="{{local}}">{{local}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and I also have an interceptorService to add the authentication to each request I make:

```
export class AuthInterceptorService {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  
    // const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');

    let request = req;

    if (window.localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      request = req.clone({
        setHeaders: { 
          // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': ['http://localhost:4200','https://localhost:8000'],
          Authorization: `Bearer ${ window.localStorage.getItem('token') }`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

**My Problem is** that I receive *400 HTTP Status* and I don't know why. Postman works and my server is configured well.

Comment: Oh! and I don't know if it's important but this is with 'OPTIONS' method, it means that is the pre-request made by angular saying what method is gonna use and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it! My request had in headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and that's server issue, not for the client. It's actually not allowed by my CORS.